# Return Row Type In Presto Udf

Tags: user-defined-functions, presto

I want to implement a udf which returns me a row.

I searched it on the net, but there is no example. In the source of presto I saw methods like [this](https://github.com/prestodb/presto/blob/97d03b67aaed70d3b0bca07fc1017008574ad0ae/presto-main/src/main/java/com/facebook/presto/operator/scalar/RowEqualOperator.java) but it takes row data type as a parameter. There is no sample how to create a row.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your output function like this:

```
@OutputFunction("row(name double,some double)")
public static void output(SomeState state, BlockBuilder out){
BlockBuilder blockBuilder = DoubleType.DOUBLE.createBlockBuilder(new BlockBuilderStatus(), 1);
    DoubleType.DOUBLE.writeDouble(blockBuilder, 1.0);
    DoubleType.DOUBLE.writeDouble(blockBuilder, 2.0);
    Block block =  blockBuilder.build();
    out.writeObject(block);
    out.closeEntry();
}
```

Here, we define parameter types for row(Name Type)

Answer (score 1):

Creating new UDF have two step process

1 Create UDF [link](https://www.qubole.com/blog/plugging-in-presto-udfs/)

2 [Register](https://www.qubole.com/blog/plugging-in-presto-udfs/) the UDF.

Ie  you have UDF Signature

```
 long Dt_TIME_ADD(string time,
                 string duration
                 [, string default_timezone = 'UTC'])


   Here 1 Long is return type 
         2 TIME_ADD is UDF Name 
         3 Parms  time ,duration and Default parm default_timezone
```

This can be called like

```
       SELECT ... WHERE TD_TIME_RANGE(time,
                           '2013-01-01',
                           TD_TIME_ADD('2013-01-01', '1d'))
```

Comment: In my question, i want to learn how can i build a row and return it in udf? I can develope udf that returns int, varchar, array, etc. But i do not know how to build a row in udf.